# Symfony2/Doctrine2 Understanding result of query

Tags: php, symfony

So I have an Alert table.  I also have an availability table.  An alert can have one or more availability.  This is expressed in my Availability class by

```
/**
 * @var \Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\Alert
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\Alert")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="availability_alert_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $availabilityAlert;
```

So availabilityAlert links to the id field in my Alert table.  So I run a query which essentially joins these two tables together (or so I think)

```
public function getAlertAvailability()
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT a, u.id
                FROM NickAlertBundle:Availability a
                JOIN a.availabilityAlert u
                WHERE u.id = a.availabilityAlert
                ORDER BY a.classLetter, a.lastUpdated'
        )
        ->getResult();
}
```

Now if I output the result of that I essentially get

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(37) "Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\Availability" 
        ["id"]=> int(5) 
    } 
    [1]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(37) "Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\Availability" 
        ["id"]=> int(5) 
    } 
    [2]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(37) "Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\Availability" 
        ["id"]=> int(6) 
    } 
}
```

So what exactly is this telling me?  I have access to the whole Availability Entity and the id of the Alert table?  If this is the case, why does it allow me to get anything from the Alert table e.g.

```
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($allAvailability[0][0]->getAvailabilityAlert()->getAlertStatus());
```

Lastly, in the output of my query above, you can see that element 0 and 1 have the same id.  This means they are linked.  Is there any way to combine them if they have the same id?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your *alert* entity, you have an *availabilityAlert* object (at really, you have a "many to one" relationship);
in other words, when you load an *alert* object, you load an array with the *availabilityAlert* associated with it.
This is done by the default, you don´t need a query for it.

Also, if you need execute a consult on the database, you can use some "*fetchings*" provided by doctrine, like *find*, *findAll*, *findBy* and *findOneBy* (`http://goo.gl/Cvve1i`).
Note that those *find options* not accept *joins*, but for your example you don't need it.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Is that still the case if I don't store an Array Collection of Availability in my Alert class?

Comment: you're selecting **a**, that is _NickAlertBundle:Availability_; try **select a.id**, it must be different on the first and the second elements of the ruturn.

Comment: Oh, I am not doing it like that anymore.  I am using my Alert Repository and doing findAll.  I was just wondering that although Availability is linked to Alert, if I dont store a collection of Availability in my Alert class can I still access it through findAll?

Comment: you'll able to load an array with those objects, but you'll need the _availability repository_ and instead of use _findAll_ call the **findById()** passing the alerta id. it'll return all availabilityAlerts with alerta id associated.

Comment: @rLinhares: is not really how you said. There are some case where you want to fetch associated objects in one shot (one query) instead of use doctrine2 lazy loading (that will produce definitely more query and if you already know that you need all linked object, it definitely make sense to load them explicitly). And it's not you said because, by default, no association are loaded but are marked for lazy loading: is slightly different :)